# How to shift the rows by one column to the right or columns to the left in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

My datasets are in the format of .tsv files and while using pd.read_table one of the files does not parse data properly.

**Current Dataset parsing looks like this:**

```
       col2    col3    col4    col5
abc     1        2      3       nan
def     4        5      6       nan
ghi     7        8      9       nan
```

**Expected parsing**

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
abc     1        2      3       
def     4        5      6       
ghi     7        8      9
```

I have 2 .tsv files that look the exact same but when they go through `pd.read_table()` one of them gets parsed like the above table where the 1st column is shifted. I don't know why there is inconsistency.

This is how I parse the data to dataframe

```
df = pd.read_table("pi_data.tsv", parse_dates=['TimeStamp'])
```

## Image of the dataset in pd

[image]

As you can see the batch column name should be above where row values are PBX****

Comment: your mean `df.reset_index()` for column right shift?

Comment: Most likely, your have a tab before "col2" in the first file. Can you provide the first few lines of each file (in a reproducible format)?

Answer (score 0):

Below line should reset the index and get the correct order of columns.

df=df.reset_index()

Reference -
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: This is not a correct approach. `reset_index` won't shift the column names.

Comment: Right, I read the question again and it looks like something wrong with the headers in the file. Can we get the sample data instead of screenshot ? Setting the column names explicitly might solve the issue but difficult to say without sample data.

Comment: Try setting the column names explicitly.

df.columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']

Answer (score 0):

If the complete file is to be loaded as a table. Reading it as csv using seperator should help

```
pd.read_csv('pi_data.tsv',sep='\t')
```